# Unable to test application on TV

Tags: webos, television, lg

EDITED:

i am trying to develop an app for LG WebOS TV. For the begining I just want to get an idea how to run/test application on real TV (in emulator it works fine), i am following the manual on LG Developers site ([link](http://developer.lge.com/webOSTV/develop/web-app/app-test)) but it does not appear on TV (can not install) as it is said in the manual. so i am kinda stack what i am missing or doing wrong.

i am downloading DRM from test site and copying it to USB stick in this path

'/developer/apps/usr/palm/applications/DRMZIPEXTRACTED' but it does not work

i am trying to test/install on my LG TV. but still no success.

i am following [this](http://developer.lge.com/webOSTV/develop/web-app/app-test) instructions. but still can not see application on tv when pluging in USB

Any ideas will be appreciated what to consider or do next coz i am realy stack.

thanks

Comment: Can you please expand your question with more details to make it easier for people to answer?  Currently it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you making a app with `Enyo` or without?
If you are making one without, have you set the `App type` to `web`, and then `sub type` to `all`?

And as you say, you have made the dir's as in the description, but in the final folder `applications`, you only need to have the folder `com.xxx.appname`.

Is that done aswell ? or do you have the zip-name as a folder, before the `com.xxx.appname`?

It should look like this: `/developer/apps/usr/palm/applications/com.xxx.appname`

I've made one yesterday, and it all worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I try to test an app to and can't see in the smart menu, I change the name `com.mycompany.app.test` in the folder applications and now is showing in my stmart menu, i hope you can too

bye sorry for the bad english (tryhard)